# WPF FrameworkElement manipulation after OnRender

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I create a custom control and draw some objects in OnRender.

Now the question is: Assume I draw 5 rectangles in OnRender. Is there a way to delete eg the 1. rectangle without to retrigger OnRender and redraw rectangles 2-5?

Or in general, is there another way, where you can update or add/remove rendering instructions, instead of rebuilding the drawing in OnRender every time something changes?

---

@ dsdel: Ok, the idea is, that the calculations in OnRender might be very heavy. You can render Text, Geometric shapes. And I ask myself, why shall I create all the Geometry and FormatedText again, if the only thing I want, is to change the position of a line. The Rectangles above just were an example. It is more a general question. Is it really necessary to recalculate all elements in a new call to OnRender instead of just updating what has changed. I mean OnRender does not render anything, it just prepares some object structures that get transfered to DirectX for rendering. So I just want to manipulate the existing object structures instead of creating new once every time a little thing changes.

Comment: I assume there is a reason that at first 5 rectangles are drawn but you did not describe what you really want to do... So please describe 'why' you want to do this. Thinking of Visibility Collapsed might not be what you are looking for?

Comment: Just draw into different Visuals. Redraw only those that have changed content.